# Complex Vectors in Matlab d

Tags: matlab

I am lost on how to make the vector

`xj = sin(pi(j-1)/10), j = 1,...,21`

in matlab.

Also I am trying to make the vector

`xj = 2-j, j=0,1,...,20.`

For the last one I tried which I am trying to get the cumulative sum without a for loop.

```
 x = 0:20
 s = cumsum(2^-x)
```

I know that the should both have relatively similiar answers but I only understand how to make simple vectors and not these complex ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the vector x<sub>j</sub> = sin(pi(j-1)/10), j = 1,...,21 you do exactly that:

```
j = 1:21;
xj = sin(pi*(j-1)/10);
```

Similarly, to make the vector x<sub>j</sub> = 2<sup>-j</sup>, j=0,1,...,20:

```
j = 0:20
xj = 2.^-j
```

Do note the `.^` operator. You usually want to apply element-wise operators in these cases.